# adding somehow reverb to a 2D array with python

Tags: python, arrays, scipy

I got a simple 2D array of values like this :

[simple array]

[image: 1]

and I want to add reverb to it (I don't know how to call it other way) in order for it to look like this, basicly with a damping/smooth effect on y values but only on +x :

[with reverb]

[image: 2]

I tried to check with scipy as i'm already using it to smooth values but didn't found out how to do it.
does anybody has an idea ?

Comment: what have you tried so far please?   also, what output are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I tried with a regular convolve function from scipy ( see here : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html ) but as it shown, it produce smoothed values on both sides, before and after peaks. i'm litteraly trying to have peaks y values to "fade" over time, so only after peaks (over the x axis). I've already isolated them, and now i'm trying to add a "fade over time/reverb" behavior to those peaks. the output should remain an array of same size as the input.

Comment: So this is a maths problem as opposed to a computation problem. You are asking what the best fit for the data is...  the question should therefore be "how can i implement `xxxx` fit on `yyyy` data with python. If you can add code, this would be helpful to describe the question.

Comment: my code as of now, in this case would just be an array of n values with mostly 0.0 values and some higher isolated peak values radomly spreaded over the array. as shown in the graph. And I'm trying to find a filtering function that could produce damping on only one "side" (+x) of each peaks. I call it reverb as this is the closes behavior to it I can think of as a comparison. for example here in the scipy convolve function it does  the damping, but on both side of the "original pulse", here i'm trying to only produce it on the right side ( +x side ) of it.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try a [Finite impulse response filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response), though it's not clear if it's exactly what you need.

[image]

This was produced by the script below.

I've assumed, given your figures, that your data is actually 1-dimensional (a "line" of numbers, not a "rectangle").

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

npts = 50
# FIR with falling sawtooth impulse response
b = np.linspace(1,0,npts,endpoint=False)

u = np.zeros(3 * npts)
u[0] = 1
u[npts + 10] = 1
u[npts + 10 + npts//2] = 1

y = signal.lfilter(b, [1], u)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2)
ax[0].stem(u)
ax[0].set_ylabel('input')
ax[1].stem(y)
ax[1].set_ylabel('output')

plt.show()
```

Comment: seems perfect !! gonna try it asap, thank you